# No 'run IntelliTest' option in VS2015 Enterprise context menu

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, vs-unit-testing-framework, intellitest

I am using VS2015 Enterprise and am trying to check out the new IntelliTest feature, but can't find the option anywhere. I created a simple function within one of my project's classes and right clicked the function and there is no 'run intellitest' option available in the context menu.

I only see Run Tests and Debug Tests.

Can someone tell me why it isn't in there. I saw many VS2015 tutorials and demos and can't follow them because I do not have the IntelliTest item anywhere in my VS2015.

Comment: There is no VS 2015 Ultimate. What version do you actually have? It's only in Enterprise Edition, if I remember correctly.

Comment: I apologize for writing Ultimate. I have Visual Studio Enterprise 2015.

Comment: What type of project is it?  Seems some project types don't support it.  https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedbackdetail/view/1986471/intellitest-for-universal-windows-platform-uwp-apps

Comment: @Dave I started to figure that out. I am trying to do it with ASP.NET 5 MVC app with a Test app created separately and it just isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

I found that IntelliTest is only visible depending on the project types in your solution. For example, the only time I was able to see it was when right clicking a function in a C# class library.